# Set numpy array rows column values to column values of another array

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to select rows with values in their first two columns matching with those of another array and set their last columns values to the last column values of that array.

I've specifically tried to do something like this:

```
import numpy as np

array_1 = np.zeros((10,3), order = "F", dtype = int)

array_2 = np.zeros((5,3), order = "F", dtype = int)

array_1[:5][:,0] = 1
array_1[:5][:,1] = 1

array_2[:,0] = 1
array_2[:,1] = 1
array_2[:,2] = 3

array_1[:,2][np.where((array_1[:,0] == array_2[:,0]) & (array_1[:,1] == array_2[:,1]))] = array_2[:,2]
```

The objective is to set the value of column 2 of rows matching to 3. (same as array_2)

I've also tried to do the same thing with masking.

It always complaints about a shape mismatch, so I assume I am doing something wrong since the objective is only to change the value of one particular column, for those row matches.

What is the way to do this?

Comment: What are the shapes of `array_1` and `array_2`?

Comment: They are different but I was hoping for this to not matter to the operation since I am only targeting the elements of the one that the other also has.

Comment: What are the shapes for `array_1[:,0].shape` and `array_2[:,0].shape`? If they are different, you cannot compare them.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. A small example of `array_1` and  `array_2` that demonstrates the problem and is representative of your actual arrays.

Comment: I have updated the code with a minimal reproducible example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve it like this:

```
import numpy as np

array_1 = np.zeros((10,3), order = "F", dtype = int)

array_2 = np.zeros((5,3), order = "F", dtype = int)

array_1[:5][:,0] = 1
array_1[:5][:,1] = 1

array_2[:,0] = 1
array_2[:,1] = 1
array_2[:,2] = 3

m = (array_1[:,:2][:,None] == array_2[:,:2]).all(-1).any(1)

array_1[:,2][m] = array_2[:,2]
```